# PHP foreach , to add 3rd sql query data

Tags: php, foreach

```php
$query = $dbm->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "tb_employees_info` WHERE att_flag = 1 ORDER BY person_id ASC");

$staffs = $query->rows;

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");

$pre_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));

$query2 = $dbm->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "tb_att_record` WHERE date = '".$pre_date."'");

$attendances = $query2->rows;

$query3 = $dbm->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "tb_device_gate_record` WHERE CAST(time AS DATE) = '".$pre_date."'");

$devices = $query3->rows;

foreach($staffs as $staff){
    $dev_permission = getEmployeeDevice($staff['id']);

    if($dev_permission == 1){
        $masterlist[] = array(
            'vip_id'    => $staff['id'],
            'name'      => $staff['name'],
            'person_id' => $staff['person_id'],
            'temp'      => '',
            'first_time'=> '',
            'last_time' => '',
            'device_id' => ''
        );
        foreach($attendances as $attendance){
            if($staff['id'] == $attendance['vip_id']){
                $sublist[] = array(
                    'vip_id'    => $staff['id'],
                    'name'      => $staff['name'],
                    'person_id' => $staff['person_id'],
                    'temp'      => $attendance['temp'],
                    'first_time'=> $attendance['first_time'],
                    'last_time' => $attendance['last_time'],
                    'device_id' => ''
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add Query 3 , device_id into the foreeach result.
the Query 3 primary key with Query 1 is id == vip_id

Comment: you'd need to do a JOIN query (seems like joining `tb_att_record` with `tb_device_gate_record`)

Comment: **joining** the table first is the best way.

Comment: Agreed, I don't see much sense in having multiple queries here to begin with